# Can I throw `std::bad_cast`?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to throw an instance of `std::bad_cast` ? The underlying question is not whether it is good or not to do this, it is only about whether `std::bad_cast` has a default constructor or not.

Thanks

Comment: If you do, God will kill a cat or something.

Comment: @AlexandreC. I hate cats too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

18.5.2 of the C++ standard says "yes", it has a no-arg constructor.